# List to nested list and dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have this one long list and want to convert it to a nested list and a dictionary.

```
L= ["a","abc","de","efg","", "b","ijk","lm","op","qr","", "c","123","45","6789"]
```

output:

```
nested list:
[["a","abc","de","efg"], ["b","ijk","lm","op","qr"], ["c","123","45","6789"]] 

dictionary: 
{"a":["abc","de","efg"],
"b":["ijk","lm","op","qr"], "c":["123","45","6789] }
```

Can anyone tell me how to do that in **python**?
And I can't import anything

Comment: What code have you tried?

Comment: what are the rules determining how you create your nested list or dictionary?  that's the first thing you need to explain.  Then as @ReinstateMonica stated, you need to provide some code to prove you've at least given it a decent attempt.  Thirdly, I doubt imports are even necessary.

Comment: There's 2 empty string in the list. I want to itterate through list and split when i == ""  (empty strings) and put everyone in nested form or something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how to convert L to a nested list:

```
L= ["a","abc","de","efg","","b","ijk","lm","op","qr","","c","123","45","6789"] 

nested_list_L = []

temp = []
for item in L:
    if item != "":
        temp.append(item)
    else:
        nested_list_L.append(temp)
        temp = []
        
nested_list_L.append(temp)
```

And here's how to convert L to a dictionary:

```
L= ["a","abc","de","efg","","b","ijk","lm","op","qr","","c","123","45","6789"] 

dict_L = {}

temp = []
key = ""
for item in L:
    if len(item) == 1:
        key = item
    elif len(item) > 1:
        temp.append(item)
    else:
        dict_L[key] = temp
        temp = []
        key = ""
        
dict_L[key] = temp
```

Answer (score 3):

I assume the groups are separated by the empty strings. For this you can use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
from itertools import groupby

data = ["a","abc","de","efg","", "b","ijk","lm","op","qr","", "c","123","45","6789"] 

nl = [list(g) for k, g in groupby(data, ''.__ne__) if k]
d = {next(g): list(g) for k, g in groupby(data, ''.__ne__) if k}

print(nl)
print(d)
```

Results:

```
[['a', 'abc', 'de', 'efg'], ['b', 'ijk', 'lm', 'op', 'qr'], ['c', '123', '45', '6789']]
{'a': ['abc', 'de', 'efg'], 'b': ['ijk', 'lm', 'op', 'qr'], 'c': ['123', '45', '6789']}
```

In the groupby I'm using `''.__ne__` which is the function for "not equal" of an empty string. This way it's only capturing groups of non-empty strings.

**EDIT**

I just read that you cannot import. Here's a solution just using a loop:

```
nl = [[]]

for s in data:
    if s:
        nl[-1].append(s)
    else:
        nl.append([])
```

And for the dict:

```
itr = iter(data)
key = next(itr)
d = {key: []}

while True:
    try: val = next(itr)
    except StopIteration: break
    if val:
        d[key].append(val)
    else:
        key = next(itr)
        d[key] = []
```

Comment: everesteye stated explicitly in the question that there can't be any imports.

Comment: @M-Chen-3 I was just editing my answer actually as I didn't read that the first time.

Comment: Understandable. Don't worry about it.

Comment: Can anyone tell me how can I extract float from a string without importing anything? isdigit() doesn't work for floats

Comment: There's a `float` method: `float(mystr)`

Comment: s = " 12 and 15 is integer and 12.5 and 14.2 is float"
a = []
b = []
c = []
for word in s.split():
    if word.isdigit():
        a.append(int(word))
    elif float(word):
        b.append(word)
    else:
        c.append(word)
print(a)
print(b)
print(c)

Comment: I'm trying something like this, but as you can see couldn't extract float... Any help without import

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, you are trying to:

1. Split a list by empty string, then
2. Convert the resulting nested list into a dictionary, using first element of each sub-list as the key and the rest as value.

You can certainly accomplish the task without any imports. To split a list, just iterate over it and build the nested list along the way:

```
def split(data, on):
    nested = []
    curr = []
    for x in data:
        if x == on:
            nested.append(curr)
            curr = []
        else:
            curr.append(x)
    if curr != [] or data[-1:] == [on]:
        nested.append(curr)
    return nested
```

Then, again, iterate over this nested list to build your desired dictionary:

```
def build_dict(key_valss):
    d = {}
    for key_vals in key_valss:
        if key_vals != []:
            key = key_vals[0]
            vals = key_vals[1:]
            d[key] = vals
    return d
```

Compose the two functions to get what you want:

```
>>> build_dict( split(data = ["a","abc","de","efg","", "b","ijk","lm","op","qr","", "c","123","45","6789"] , on = '') )
{'a': ['abc', 'de', 'efg'], 'b': ['ijk', 'lm', 'op', 'qr'], 'c': ['123', '45', '6789']}
```

Comment: thank you for your help. I'm stuck in finding float now. Can you tell me how to extract float from a sentence without using import?